# dask array gradient multiplication

Tags: python, dask

I am trying to use dask arrays to do image processing on very large datasets. A part of this is getting the gradient, doing some processing and multiplying them with each other. However, this results in an error.

Minimal example without the processing step:

```
import dask.array as da
data = da.random.random((100, 100), chunks=(10, 10))
grad0, grad1 = da.gradient(data, axis=(0, 1))
(grad0 * grad1).compute()
```

Gives the error: `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (8,12) (10,10)`.

Should this work?

I'm using dask 0.18.0 (the most recent version on PyPI).

Comment: This looks like a bug report.  I recommend closing it and opening up a bug report on the Dask issue tracker at https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/new .  I also recommend pinging `@jakirkham`

Comment: Bug report: https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/3633

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was due to a bug in `dask.array`, and has been fixed in the development branch: https://github.com/dask/dask/pull/3647